# Merging images on mac

Tags: software-recommendation, macbook-pro

Say you have a picture of a dog and a cat. You want to merge parts of the dog's face onto the cat's face creating a cat-dog fusion. What MacBook Pro programs can i get for free in order to do this?

Comment: What kind of research did you already do on this?

Comment: I think Preview has already all the features required.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/). It's a free program that can offer many of the tools that Photoshop does.